# How to print in table-like structure on receipt ESC/POS

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-printing

I'm trying to print a receipt using android and Bluetooth printer. I've managed to print text normally and using ESC/POS command for some of the texts. However I can't figure out how to print a table-like structure like:

[image]

I've tried to use reverse-feed but the printer doesn't seems to support it (I tried with a few commands but didn't work). Currently the only way I can think of is to calculate the length of each number and add space between them to look like a table. Is there a way to do this by using ESC/ POS command?

Comment: did u find a solution ? i'm looking for the same thing

Comment: @jht It's been a long time since I've worked on this project, but I think I ended up having to add space to the characters to make them appear as a table instead of using any command. This was because I can't find any command that would work as I needed.

Comment: Looking for the same thing.

Comment: Maybe you can generate an image and print image? I am also having same issue and I think I'll end up with doing that.

Comment: i guess there will be quality issues with printing an image vs printing a string directly...

Comment: @EjazKarim how to print an image